# how can I make an oval button elevated (with shadow) while having a background image?

Tags: kotlin, button, shadow, android-elevation, android-studio-flamingo

I am trying to make an oval button with shadow/elevated features,while having a background image, but failed to do so , as I think it's due to background image.how can I make a button elevated (with shadow) having background image? Also Can I make it a floating button which opens a new empty activity?
following is my code.
i am working on kotlin android studio flamingo 2022
windows 10 x64

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bckground6"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:elevation="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!--    android:scaleType="fitXY"-->
    <!--    android:background="@drawable/bckground"-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:elevation="14dp"


        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="MOBILE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:translationY="60dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="A OWNER"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:translationY="95dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text="MAIN"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#FFFDFD"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:translationY="-310dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text="Mob"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="-410dp" /

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed = "false">
    <shape android:shape = "oval">
        <solid android:color = "#A8D2E7"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed = "true">
    <shape android:shape = "oval">
        <solid android:color = "#A8D2E7"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```